# Google circle visualization not appearing

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want to achieve the circle visualisation as shown in this page, with specified geojson data in the file already.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/earthquakes

My data is in the form

```
var data = {'features': [{'properties': {}, 'geometry': {'coordinates': [1.3944646999999999, 103.74665109999999], 'type': 'Point'}, 'type': 'Feature'}], 'type': 'FeatureCollection'};
```

with many more points. I have changed the `map.data.loadGeoJson` to `map.data.addGeoJson`. However, when i open the file, the plain map shows with no points or circles whatsoever.

Here is my full code with the API key removed. Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      var data = {'features': [{'properties': {}, 'geometry': {'coordinates': [1.3944646999999999, 103.74665109999999], 'type': 'Point'}, 'type': 'Feature'}], 'type': 'FeatureCollection'};

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 2,
          center: {lat: -33.865427, lng: 151.196123},
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

        map.data.addGeoJson(data); //add the data here

        map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
          var magnitude = 4; //feature.getProperty('mag');
          return {
            icon: getCircle(magnitude)
          };
        });
      }

      function getCircle(magnitude) {
        return {
          path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
          fillColor: 'red',
          fillOpacity: .2,
          scale: Math.pow(2, magnitude) / 2,
          strokeColor: 'white',
          strokeWeight: .5
        };
      }


    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[key_removed]&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your coordinates are backwards ([GeoJSON coordinates](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#positions) are ordered longitude, latitude):

```
'coordinates': [1.3944646999999999, 103.74665109999999],
```

should be:

```
'coordinates': [103.74665109999999, 1.3944646999999999],
```

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var data = {
  'features': [{
    'properties': {},
    'geometry': {
      'coordinates': [103.74665109999999, 1.3944646999999999],
      'type': 'Point'
    },
    'type': 'Feature'
  }],
  'type': 'FeatureCollection'
};

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 2,
    center: {
      lat: -33.865427,
      lng: 151.196123
    },
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });

  map.data.addGeoJson(data); //add the data here

  map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    var magnitude = 4; //feature.getProperty('mag');
    return {
      icon: getCircle(magnitude)
    };
  });
}

function getCircle(magnitude) {
  return {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    fillColor: 'red',
    fillOpacity: .2,
    scale: Math.pow(2, magnitude) / 2,
    strokeColor: 'white',
    strokeWeight: .5
  };
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: ...I cant believe I missed that. Thank you so much!